# How to encode a 2D array in JSON format?

Tags: php, android, sql, json, database

Lets say I have a table like so:

First |   Last  |  Age

John  |   Doe   |  25

Jane  |   Doe   |  23

How can I set up php code so I could access each element seperately? like so:

[first:John  last:Doe  age:25]

[first:Jane  last:Doe  age:23]

where first, last and age are keys and they would return the respective values.

My end goal is to populate an Android list view with all this data, and each card has first, last and age of different people.

Comment: Json_encode($array); ?

Comment: @Doug well I understand that, I meant what sql command should I use to separate the data? Would, "SELECT * FROM my_table" work?